# How to auto-replace content of .desktop-file depending on current state of a script

Tags: bash, scripts, icons, .desktop

**Let's have an easy example:**

I run a script which is setting a program either to mode "*on*" (= 1) or to mode "*off*" (= 0). The script is getting actuated by a simple click on the regarding `.desktop`-file.

---

**The script looks like that:**

```
#!/bin/bash

DESKT=/home/user/program.desktop

if [ $(systemctl --user status program | grep -c running) = 0 ]; then
    systemctl --user start program
    echo "Icon=program_active" >> "$DESKT"
    echo "Name=Program working" >> "$DESKT"
else
    systemctl --user stop program
    echo "Icon=Program_inactive" >> "$DESKT"
    echo "Name=Program stopped" >> "$DESKT"
fi
```

---

**The .desktop-file looks like that:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Program
Exec=program
Icon=program-inactive
```

---

**My question now is:**

If I switch on my program by actuating the `.desktop`-file, the name of the `.desktop`-file is getting changed to "Program working" what is fully correct! Unfortunately, the previous icon ("`program_inactive`") doesn't get changed to the now needed icon "`program_active`".

Instead of replacing the inactive-icon with the correct active-icon, there will be written a completely new line with "`Icon=program_active`" instead of replacing the existing line "`Icon=program_inactive`". Because of that, there are now two lines with "`Icon=blabla`" what is completely useless of course.

What do I have to do to replace the existing icon-line instead of writing a useless new line? Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: That's an interesting idea and at the same time a blatant misuse of `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try overwriting the file instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

DESKT=/home/user/program.desktop

if [ $(systemctl --user status program | grep -c running) = 0 ]; then
    systemctl --user start program
    icon=active
    name=working
else
    systemctl --user stop program
    icon=inactive
    name=stopped
fi

cat > "$DESKT" <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Program $name
Exec=program
Icon=program_$icon
EOF
```

#### Explanation:

The `cat <<EOF` will copy anything until the next `EOF` by itself, interpreting variables.